# MySQL Throws error after defining the location of table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this 'information' table below with 4 columns in it:  `'creator_id','viewer_id','date_format','donation'`

```
CREATE TABLE information (
    creator_id INT NOT NULL,
    viewer_id INT NOT NULL,
    date_format DATE NOT NULL,
    donation INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT 
    INTO twitch.information(creator_id,viewer_id,date_format,donation) 
    VALUES
    (10,11,'2014-01-02',34),
    (20,14,'2014-01-02',150),
    (30,15,'2014-01-02',717),
    (31,17,'2014-01-02',177),
    (32,17,'2014-01-06',737),
    (33,16,'2014-01-07',37),
    (40,18,'2016-03-08',442),
    (41,19,'2016-03-09',142),
    (42,10,'2016-03-10',152),
    (43,11,'2016-03-11',512),
    (44,12,'2016-01-12',340),
    (60,0,'2012-01-02',1000),
    (70,1,'2012-01-02',100);

SELECT creator_id,
    MAX(SUM(donation)/COUNT(donation)) AS "TOP AVG DONATION CREATOR ON YEAR 2014 (January)"
    WHERE date_format = "2014-01-02"
    FROM twitch.information;
```

I was approaching for to find the creator_id that have the highest average of donation on date of '2014-01-02' but my output console throws this error: `Error code 1064: you have error in your SQL Syntax; check the manual corresponding...`

I believe there's something wrong with my syntax but I couldn't tell what is it.

Comment: `SELECT...FROM...WHERE`. This is pretty basic, if I'm honest

Comment: @HoneyBadger Indeed, but coming back to SQL after month of break is not easy to remember the basic.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Error still appears but this time its 'FROM is not valid  at this position...' mind you help? i've done several googling but no answer

Comment: change order: FROM twitch.information WHERE date_format = "2014-01-02";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the problem the where clause must appear after the from, you don't need to do a division (which is risky because of possible divide by zero exceptions). You can use AVG, so "the creator_id that have the highest average of donation on date of '2014-01-02'" can be found that way:

```
SELECT creator_id,
AVG(donation) AS averageDonation
FROM information
WHERE date_format = "2014-01-02"
GROUP BY creator_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1;
```

...or if you want it more clear:

```
SELECT creator_id,
AVG(donation) AS averageDonation
FROM information
WHERE date_format = "2014-01-02"
GROUP BY creator_id
ORDER BY averageDonation DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to group your data when using aggregation functions :

```
SELECT 
     creator_id
     , MAX(SUM(donation) / COUNT(donation)) AS "TOP AVG DONATION CREATOR ON YEAR 2014 (January)"
FROM twitch.information
WHERE date_format = "2014-01-02"
GROUP BY creator_id;
```

Update :

Use AVG aggregation function which handles division by zero potential error :

```
SELECT 
     creator_id
     , MAX(AVG(donation)) AS "TOP AVG DONATION CREATOR ON YEAR 2014 (January)"
FROM twitch.information
WHERE date_format = "2014-01-02"
GROUP BY creator_id;
```

Comment: This is very risky due to possible divide by zero exceptions, furthermore it's incorrect usage of group functions, so this query will not be executed.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Incorrect usage of group functions, can you explain a bit further?

Comment: That's difficult to put in a comment, better would be you have a look on documentations/tutorials like https://sebhastian.com/mysql-invalid-use-group-function/

Comment: Please have look on documentations. The second query is also incorrect and won't be executed. You can't do MAX(AVG...) like that.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Thanks. I updated the answer to provide a solution which handles zero division.